# X-Y Graph Block in Simulink

Tags: matlab

How an x-y graph block in simulink can be edit to show or add the following;

1- Main title,
2- Grid on,
3-  X and Y labels.

Comment: You are splitting up your questions in a way no one can follow without knowing your previous one. Either discuss this via comments in your previous question or create a question which stands for it own.

Comment: Just beacuse Luis asked me to make a new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn on hidden handles property to modify these figures. For example, to change the title you should do,

```
cv = get(0,'showhiddenhandles');
set(0,'showhiddenhandles','on');
title('my title');
set(0,'showhiddenhandles', cv); % Reset original value
```

Comment: shh = get(0,'ShowHiddenHandles');
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','On')
set(gcf,'menubar','figure')
set(gcf,'CloseRequestFcn','closereq')
set(gcf,'DefaultLineClipping','Off')
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles',shh)
This is very good code which enables a user to modify title, axis grids...etc