# Plotting Specific axes from simulink scope data in matlab

Tags: matlab, scope, axis, simulink, axes

I have a scope with 6 data inputs and six axes. I want to be able to use the plot function in matlab to get a specific access from the scope. What is the best way to do this then using multiple subplots of separate scopes.

Comment: I am not clear on what you want. If you want to use MATLAB plot commands one way is to log the signal to MATLAB workspace and then use plot commands on the logged data.

Comment: I have the scope setup to send data to the workspace. I want to be able to select and plot specific axis from the scope that has 6 axes.

Comment: See answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203735/x-y-graph-block-in-simulink/24517762#24517762 to get handles of scope figures. You then would need to add click handlers to plot your data.